# How to use AsyncTask class input params

Tags: android, upload, android-asynctask

I try to make an AsyncTask class for upload variable temperature in background.How i insert params? Url,variable?I make this code but i have errors...

```
public class SimpleHttpPut extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

//public static void main(String urlt,int t) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlt);
    try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temp",String.valueOf(t)));
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 // }
 return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

See my answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827677/how-to-pass-a-parameters-to-asynctask-ksoap2/13827936#13827936)... it explains passing parameters directly to the `doInBackground` function as well as to the Aynctask class itself, as well as calling a callback function in the calling activity.

The to the point answer in your case is passing a String array of params to doInBackground

In calling activity:

```
//params to pass to doInBackground
private String[] params= {"mynamespace", "mymethods", "mysoap", "myuser", "mypass"}; 

//Pass your args array and the current activity to the AsyncTask
new MyTask("my arg1", 10).execute(params);
```

In Asynctask :

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private String stringArg;
    private int intArg;

    public MyTask(String stringArg, int intArg){
        this.stringArg = stringArg;
        this.intArg = intArg;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //These are params local to this function
        String _NAMESPACE = params[0];
        String _METHODNAME = params[1];
        String _SOAPACTION = params[2];
        String _USER_NAME = params[3];
        String _USER_PASS= params[4];

        //intArg & stringArg are now available throughout the class

        //Do background stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one string and one integer.How i use this?

Comment: You can use a constructor for your Asynctask class and initialize as many variables there as you want... I updated the above to use an int and a String that are private to the class.